# Electron 19 showOpenDialog "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')"

Tags: javascript, electron, dialog

I have updated electron to version 19 but I have an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')

I have a function to save file:

```
window.SaveFile = function (options, callBack) {
    const {
        name, //the name showed for the extension/s
        extensions,
        fileName
    } = options;
    let filters = [{ name: name, extensions: Array.isArray(extensions) ? extensions : [extensions] }];
    dialog.showSaveDialog(null, { properties: ['saveFile'], name: [name], filters: filters, icon: 'main.ico', defaultPath: (fileName || name) + '.' + extensions }, (returnValue) => {
        callBack(returnValue);
    });
}
```

But `dialog` is undefined.
In index.js I have set the:

```
webPreferences: {
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    nodeIntegration: true
}
```

My required in electron is

```
const { ipcRenderer, dialog, remote, ipcMain } = require('electron');
```

but `dialog` and `remote` are undefined.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you did not have the error with the same code and electron version <19?

Comment: My previous version was electron 6.0.7 and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

A while back, the `remote` module was deprecated (see [Electron's breaking changes document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-140)). Because [`dialog`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog) is a main process module, you'll now have to open the dialog from the main process.

This, of course, complicates things a little bit, but with `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` this should be easy to achieve.

Assuming you have `const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");` in your renderer process:

```js
window.SaveFile = function (options, callBack) {
    ipcRenderer.invoke ("save-file", options).then (returnValue => {
        callBack (returnValue);
    });
}
```

And then in your main process:

```js
ipcMain.handle ("save-file", async (event, options) => {
    const {
        name, //the name showed for the extension/s
        extensions,
        fileName
    } = options;
    let filters = [{ name: name, extensions: Array.isArray(extensions) ? extensions : [extensions] }];
    var returnValue = await dialog.showSaveDialog(
        null,
        {
            properties: ['saveFile'],
            name: [name],
            filters: filters,
            icon: 'main.ico',
            defaultPath: (fileName || name) + '.' + extensions
        }
    );

    return returnValue;
});
```